# How is minimax static tree built?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, minimax

Consider I am building tic-tac-toe from scratch, I am currently trying to use minimax algorithm so that I can have computer as player 1 and myself as player 2. I think I understand minimax algorithm ( as some form of depth first search).

My question is, how is the tree that the minimax algorithm work on made in the first place? all the examples that I see has tree already made out with some numerical value in there terminal node.

eg:

```
       max
  / \  
       min
 /\ /\
7 2 1 5
```

I have seen this simpler version of tree and how path to node with value 1 in the terminal node is chosen. How do we get the have of 7,2,1 and 5 in the first place?? lets say in tic-tac-toe .. my curiosity lingers here.

Comment: a quick search gave me this http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax

Comment: Where did you find the description you have included in the question? To my understanding, a leaf of the tree can have only three values, basically `{1,0,-1}` indicating victory of player 1, draw, and victory of player 2.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking two questions. I'll address the second one first. You asked how do we get the values in terminal nodes in the first place. This depends on what type of game we are dealing with. For tic-tac-toe, all leaf nodes will either equal -1, 0 , or 1. -1 represents a loss, 0 a tie, and 1 a win. Every node must be evaluated to see if it is a terminal node (i.e. if the game is over) and if it is, assign it the appropriate value.The reason that you often see other values in search trees is because in more complex games, the entire tree cannot be evaluated, so a heuristic evaluation function is applied, usually containing a wide range of values. But for tic-tac-toe this is irrelevant.

You also asked how is the minimax tree made in this first place. A standard minimax tree is made using recursion. The pseudocode simplified for tictactoe looks like this

```
function minimax(depth,maximizingPlayer)
      if(node is terminal)
            return value;
      if (maximizingPlayer)
            bestValue  = -infinity;
            for each possible legal move 
                  makeMove(move)
                  value = minimax(depth-1,false);
                  bestValue = max(bestValue,value);
                  unmakeMove(move);
            return bestValue
      else // minimizing player
            bestValue  = infinity;
            for each possible legal move 
                  makeMove(move)
                  value = minimax(depth-1,true);
                  bestValue = min(bestValue,value);
                  unmakeMove(move);
            return bestValue
```